# How to operate with tempdb transaction log file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2005 instance and I got an error saying:

```
The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full
```

Is it wise to shrink tempdb transaction log or give it more free space from the disk? How do you usually monitor or operate the transaction log of the tempdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preallocating based on expected usage and options (how much temp tables, sorting in tempdb on/off, rowversion based isolation level on/off, etc.) is fine.